# Google Analytics don't show page view title

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using [google-analytics-plugin](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) to connect google analytics with ionic 1.

In app.js,

```
/* Google Analytics */
if(typeof analytics !== undefined) {
    analytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-XXXXXXXXX-X");
    console.log("Connected Google Analytics");
} else {
    console.log("Google Analytics Unavailable");
}
```

In controller.js, I couldn't call 'analytics' directly, so I called 'eventListener'.

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        if(typeof analytics !== undefined) {
            analytics.trackView("Login");
        }
    }, false);
}

.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        if(typeof analytics !== undefined) {
            analytics.trackView("PlaylistsCtrl");
        }
    }, false);
}
```

It connected to GoogleAnalytics but don't show the pageview title. Count is increased but show two controllers as a same page.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what should I fix to show pageview title ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, are your pages titles set ?

Comment: Hi, I'm new to google analytics. How should I set the page title?

Comment: No I meant in your application the title tag

Comment: I think I haven't. How to do it?

Comment: https://moz.com/blog/seo-meta-tags 
If your title tag is not present then you can't see it in Analytics. Try adding a `<title>Test</title>`tag and check in Analytics. Then if it's your problem you're going to have to update the title tag according to your routes changes

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following to show the page title

```
window.ga.trackView(pagename);
```